# distance between two parallel lines

Tags: vectors

Is the following formula true as I've just used it and have got the wrong answer and I can't see where I've gone wrong.

$$\frac{|(p-a)X d|}{|d|}$$
where p and a are pints on each line, d is the direction vector of the lines. X standing as cross product - was't sure what symbol to use for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be correct indeed

$$|(p-a)\times d|=|p-a|\,|d|\,\sin \theta$$

and therefore

$$\frac{|(p-a)\times d|}{|d|}=|p-a|\,\sin \theta$$

As an alternative and to check we can take a fixed point $P_0$ on a line and the parametric form of a point $Q(t)$ on the second line and use that

$$(P-Q(t))\cdot d=0$$

and find $Q_0=Q(t_0)$.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll check over my workings again then

Comment: If you show your work here I can check it!

Comment: Not in the comment but editing your question.